# MATLAB: Problems with dwt2 using uint8 values

Tags: image, matlab, wavelet

When trying this piece of code:

```
[X, map] = imread('pirate.tif');
[cA,cH,cV,cD] = dwt2(X, 'haar');
```

I get the following error: **Undefined function 'dwt2' for input arguments of type 'uint8'**.
Isn't *dwt2* suppose to handle uint8 values?

Thx for your time...

Comment: to exclude the most obvious reason: do you have the wavelet toolbox? Can you provide your example picture or similar?

Comment: Make sure you have `dtw2.m` file on your PC.

Comment: Do this - "which dwt2"

Comment: "which dwt2" gives me: 'dwt2' not found. So I don't have the toolbox. Thanks guys for your quick responses! I will buy it right now...

Comment: Then you don't have the wavelet toolbox and you can't use this function. So the important part of the error is "Undefined function 'dwt2'" rather then "for input arguments of type 'uint8'"

Comment: Yes, I got confused by the second part of the error message. But again, thx for your help!